# Can pip (python2) and pip3 (python3) coexist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I always thought that pip was for Python 2 and pip3 was for Python 3.  To install the different versions of pip I have done the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

then I get the following as one would expect:

```
$ pip --version
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$ pip3 --version
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

Those are old versions, though, so I do the following:

```
$ sudo pip install pip --upgrade
```

and I get this:

```
$ pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
$ pip3 --version
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

and when I do a pip3 install for some package, I get the following message:

```
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Well, I already ran that, so I try this:

```
$ sudo pip3 install pip --upgrade
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Successfully installed pip-19.0.3
```

But now I get this:

```
$ pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)
$ pip3 --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

Is that correct?  Does this matter?  Does a pip version from Python 3.5 work for installing Python 2 packages?

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer provided by @furas, these are all the commands I run to get updated versions of pip and pip3 installed correctly:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip --yes
sudo apt-get install python3-pip --yes
sudo python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade
sudo python -m pip install pip --upgrade --force # this line fixes the pip install to point to the python2 version instead of the python3 version
```

and that yields the following:

```
$ pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
$ pip3 --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

Comment: update `pip` for Python 2 using `python -m pip install -U pip` and it should put correct `pip`

Comment: you can also add `--force` to `python -m pip install -U --force pip`. Use `which pip` to find path to `pip` - I have `/usr/local/bin/pip`. The same with `which pip3`. it is python's script and you can see in first line `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/python3.5`. Rest code should be the same for all versions.

Comment: you should have also `pip2` or even `pip2.7`, `pip3.5` Write in console `pip` and press tab - it should show all programs which start with `pip`

Comment: @furas, I did the following and it worked: sudo pip install pip --upgrade --force - now when I type pip --version I get "pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)".  I'm guessing I should be good?

Comment: If you want, type that up as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every Python should have own `pip` because every Python may use different version of the same module and every Python installs modules in different folder.

You can use `Python2` to reinstall module `pip` for `Python2` and it should create file with correct name `pip`

```
python -m pip install -U --force pip
```

You should also have `pip`, `pip2`, `pip2.7`, `pip3`, `pip3.5`.
You can even have `pip3.6`, `pip3.7` at the same time.

If you write in console `pip` and press `tab` and it should show you all programs which start with word `pip`

You can find full path for `pip` with

```
which pip
```

and you can open it in text editor to see if it is python's script.

Different `pip` have different first line - ie. `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/python3.5`.
Rest code should be the same for all versions.

Comment: After installing python 3's pip (and having it overwrite python 2's pip), using the --force flag combined with the use of "python -m pip" to force the python 2 interpreter to run the pip install solved the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: run `which python` to check the version. then `python[VERSION] pip ...` will be worked, thus `python3.7 pip ...`

Comment: `python -m pip install -U --force pip` did  not work for me. However, I did install a `pip2` using the script `get-pip.py` from [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-20.04/)

Comment: @lui this command wasn't for installing `pip` - all `Python 2.x` and some older `Python 3.x` need to install it using `get-pip.py`. This command was only to upgrade existing `pip` and replace `pip` which installs modules for `python 3.x` with `pip` which installs modules for `python 2.x`. Currently when you install `Python 3.x` then it installs `pip` automatically and it also replaces previous `pip` (for `Python 2.x` or  older `Python 3.x`) with `pip` for current `Python 3.x`.