# Should I use pip or pip3?

Tags: python

Eventually, every single time I install a new Linux distribution I do `sudo apt-get install python3`.

However, once installed I always get confused. `python` is Python 2.7 and `python3` is Python 3.x. But also it appears that `pip` is for Python 2 and `pip3` for Python 3. That said most tutorials I see on Internet always use the traditional `pip install` even though it is about Python 3.

How should I deal with this? Should I simply continue to put this annoying `3` every time I use Python (`pip3`, `ipython3`, `python3`...)? In most of my lectures I read that creating a symlink `python->python3` is a bad practice. Is that correct?

Comment: To add: creating a symlink is dangerous because other programs may expect `python` to be a specific version of python (e.g. 2.7 instead of 3.x)

Comment: There is a related PEP: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394 It is about the 'python' naming, but 'pip' naming just mirrors the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip or pip3 to install packages for Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832533/pip-or-pip3-to-install-packages-for-python-3)

Comment: For a new Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installation I found only python3 installed but no `pip` or `pip3`. After installing `sudo apt install python3-pip`, `/usr/bin/pip` and `/usr/bin/pip3` appeared. Checking MD5 sums for these, they show as identical: `md5sum /usr/bin/pip3` equals `mdsum /usr/bin/pip`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `python3 -m pip` or `python -m pip`. That will use the correct `pip` for the python version you want. This method is mentioned in the [`pip` documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#running-pip):

> `python -m pip` executes `pip` using the Python interpreter you specified as `python`. So `/usr/bin/python3.7 -m pip` means you are executing `pip` for your interpreter located at `/usr/bin/python3.7`.

Symlinking `python->python3` is a bad idea because some programs might rely on `python` being python 2. Though, I have seen some Dockerfiles symlink `python->python3`, like [TensorFlow's CPU dockerfile](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7cfa63117f97b4eea8fd6fb5197c87630749ac32/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/cpu.Dockerfile#L40) (it's less of an issue in a Docker image). Coincidentally, that same Dockerfile uses the `python3 -m pip install` syntax that I recommend.

Comment: Why nobody uses `python3 -m pip` in their tutorials?

Comment: because it is commonly understood to refer to mean "pip, in whatever capacity you use it". On my system `pip` points to the python3 pip, as packaged by miniconda. On other systems it might be different

Comment: @nowox - i also haven't seen `python3 -m pip` used much, but the pip documentation does include it: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#running-pip

Answer (score 4):

Whether the correct command for Python 3 is `pip` or `pip3` or (say) `gaschplutzga` depends on a number of factors.

If you only have Python 3, and you have a command named `pip`, that's probably safe to use. Going forward, this will be the simple, obvious, safe answer in more and more places.

If you have both Python 2 and Python 3, and there is a command called `pip3` installed on your system, *probably* that's the correct one to use.

More generally, you can go through your `PATH` and look for commands with suitable names. On Unix-like systems with a POSIX-compatible shell, try the commands `command -V pip3` and `command -V pip`. (On Windows systems, maybe try `where pip3` and `where pip`, or pray to whatever dark deity informed your choice of operating system.)

If you receive output like

```
/opt/random/nonstandard/whoa/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

you can try each of these in turn with the full path and adding the `--version` option to have them identify themselves. When you specify the full path, you are bypassing the system's `PATH` mechanism entirely. For example,

```
/opt/random/nonstandard/whoa/pip --version
```

might identify itself as belonging to Python version 3.2.1. If that's the one you want, and it's at the top of your `PATH`, you can simply rely on the `PATH` to give you this version when you type just `pip`. If not, perhaps you can shuffle your `PATH` (but understand that this changes the resolution order for all commands in the directory whose position you change) or create a simple alias or wrapper which bypasses the `PATH` for this particular command in your personal account. On Unix-like systems with a POSIX-compatible shell, this might look like

```bash
alias pip=/opt/random/nonstandard/whoa/pip
```

(to persist this across sessions, you'd add this to your `.profile` or similar - for Bash, try `.bash_profile` if it exists; for Zsh, try `.zshrc`. The full scoop for each shell is more complicated than I can squeeze into these narrow parentheses); on Windows, you *might* be able to control this by setting the environment variable `PY_PYTHON`, but there's a [huge can of worms](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) behind that "might".

Some sites and OSes / distros have additional wrappers or conventions which introduce additional options; if you use a specific package manager, perhaps also study its documentation. (One common example is Anaconda, though I don't believe it affects the naming or location of `pip` specifically.)

One common arrangement is to use `python -m pip` instead of the bare `pip` command; this reasonably expects that whichever `python` version you run will be able to figure out how to find its specific version of `pip` from its module library. Everything about how to select a specific `pip` binary above also applies to the logic for finding a specific `python` binary; so (as long as it isn't pathologically misconfigured) `/opt/random/nonstandard/whoa/python -m pip` will run the correct `pip` version for that Python version. You could argue that this only pushes the problem to a different corner, but it's convenient if you have multiple Python versions to have a simple way to select the correct `pip` for each with a simple, unified mechanism.

On Windows, probably use `py -m pip` and expect the `py` wrapper to select the correct Python binary. The `py` command offers convenience functionality to select either Python 2 or Python 3 if both are installed. Going forward, there are plans to make this wrapper available on other platforms, too.

Answer (score 3):

> creating a symlink python->python3 is a bad practice. Is that correct?

Sometimes. Some OSs (looking at you, macOS) deeply rely on `python` pointing to a Python 2 interpreter for internal tools and tasks. Deleting the shipped Python 2 interpreter (or aliasing `python` to a Python 3 interpreter) will break stuff. [How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4/)

Comment: For the record, this is no longer true. As of MacOS Ventura (v 13) the OS no longer requires or even offers an option to install Python 2 as part of the system install. Increasingly, the same is true for any Linux distro which previously had system tools which depended on Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

**Use virtual environments**, then `pip` would be associated with the `python` used to create that virtual environment. Whether you use `pip` or `pip3`, it will be equivalent to `python3 -m pip` as mentioned in [jakub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61664746/2745495). Also, given that Python 2.7 is already EOL (which means you will most likely work with Python 3) and that `pip install`-ing things onto the system packages should be avoided, then a virtual environment would be helpful here.

For example, using `pipenv`:

```
$ pipenv --python=/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3

$ pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...

(TEMP) $ pip --version
pip 20.2.3 from /Users/me/.venvs/temp2-SbXvZiFd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
(TEMP) $ pip3 --version
pip 20.2.3 from /Users/me/.venvs/temp2-SbXvZiFd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

For example, using `venv`:

```
$ python3.8 -m venv .venv
$ source .venv/bin/activate

(.venv) $ pip --version
pip 20.2.3 from /Users/me/temp2/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
(.venv) $ pip3 --version
pip 20.2.3 from /Users/me/temp2/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

The virtual environment takes care of making sure `pip` or `pip3` in this env refers to the `pip` from the correct Python version. You can then happily follow tutorials that still use `pip install something` (unless of course that tutorial refers to a Python 2.7 or a system-wide installation).

Answer (score 0):

You can install `pip` *through* `pip3` and this should resolve this issue.

```sh
$ pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Notice that `pip` here is of Python 2.7 (in this example).

You can then force `pip3` of Python 3.X to install `pip` under itself.

```sh
$ sudo pip3 install pip --upgrade
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Successfully installed pip-19.0.3
```

Once you check this again, it should reference Python 3.X so you don't have to deal with 
what is what.

```sh
$ pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

I doubt you'll want to use Python 2 after this, but if you do happen to work with Python 2 code, you can create a virtual environment to access those commands again. Otherwise, you won't have to worry about the `pip` or `pip3` distinction after this.

Not really a duplicate of this question, but this helped me suggest this answer: [Can pip (python2) and pip3 (python3) coexist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55819906/can-pip-python2-and-pip3-python3-coexist)

Comment: If you run `which -a pip`, you will see that both python2 and python3 `pip` still exist, so finding the correct `pip` is a matter of `PATH` configuration.

Comment: (The `which` command is nonstandard; yours might not exist, or might not support an `-a` option. The POSIX standard command is `command -V`, and/or `type`.)

Answer (score 0):

Pip is for python version less than 3. and pip3 is used when you want to install packages for python version 3 or higher.